# Installing MapServer using rpms in Chef 12

Tags: chef-infra, centos7, rpm, mapserver

I've to install MapServer 7.0.5 on CentOS 7 using Chef ...

I've built rpms using this spec file ...

```
%global ini_name 40-mapserver.ini
%global project_owner mapserver
%global project_name mapserver
# MapServer doesn't support PHP 7 yet. See:
# https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/issues/5252
%global php_mapscript 0
%global commit 208bb3a10fccdc9c1bdab175915072270abb1b45
%global shortcommit %(c=%{commit}; echo ${c:0:7})

Name:           mapserver
Version:        7.0.5
Release:        3.git%{shortcommit}%{?dist}
Summary:        Environment for building spatially-enabled internet applications

Group:          Development/Tools
License:        BSD
URL:            http://www.mapserver.org

Source0:        https://github.com/%{project_owner}/%{project_name}/archive/%{commit}/%{project_name}-%{commit}.tar.gz

Requires:       httpd
Requires:       dejavu-sans-fonts

BuildRequires:  cairo-devel
BuildRequires:  cmake
BuildRequires:  curl-devel
BuildRequires:  fcgi-devel
BuildRequires:  freetype-devel
BuildRequires:  fribidi-devel
BuildRequires:  gd-devel >= 2.0.16
BuildRequires:  gdal-devel
BuildRequires:  geos-devel
BuildRequires:  giflib-devel
BuildRequires:  httpd-devel
BuildRequires:  libjpeg-devel
BuildRequires:  libpng-devel
BuildRequires:  libtiff-devel
BuildRequires:  libxml2-devel
BuildRequires:  libXpm-devel
BuildRequires:  libxslt-devel
BuildRequires:  mysql-devel
BuildRequires:  harfbuzz-devel
BuildRequires:  pam-devel
BuildRequires:  perl-generators
BuildRequires:  perl(ExtUtils::MakeMaker)
BuildRequires:  postgresql-devel
BuildRequires:  proj-devel
BuildRequires:  readline-devel
BuildRequires:  swig
BuildRequires:  zlib-devel


%description
Mapserver is an internet mapping program that converts GIS data to
map images in real time. With appropriate interface pages,
Mapserver can provide an interactive internet map based on
custom GIS data.


%package  libs
Summary:  %{summary}

%description libs
This package contains the libs for mapserver.


%package  devel
Summary:        Development files for mapserver
Requires:       %{name} = %{version}

%description devel
This package contains development files for mapserver.

%if 0%{php_mapscript}
%package -n php-%{name}
Summary:        PHP/Mapscript map making extensions to PHP
Group:          Development/Languages
BuildRequires:  php-devel
Requires:       php-gd%{?_isa}
Requires:       php(zend-abi) = %{php_zend_api}
Requires:       php(api) = %{php_core_api}

%description -n php-%{name}
The PHP/Mapscript extension provides full map customization capabilities within
the PHP scripting language.
%endif # end php_mapscript


%package perl
Summary:        Perl/Mapscript map making extensions to Perl
Group:          Development/Languages
Requires:       %{name} = %{version}-%{release}
Requires: perl(:MODULE_COMPAT_%(eval "`%{__perl} -V:version`"; echo $version))

%description perl
The Perl/Mapscript extension provides full map customization capabilities
within the Perl programming language.

%package python
Summary:        Python/Mapscript map making extensions to Python
Group:          Development/Languages
BuildRequires:  python2-devel
Requires:       %{name} = %{version}-%{release}

%description python
The Python/Mapscript extension provides full map customization capabilities
within the Python programming language.

%package java
Summary:        Java/Mapscript map making extensions to Java
Group:          Development/Languages
BuildRequires:  java-devel
Requires:       %{name} = %{version}-%{release}
Requires:       java-headless

%description java
The Java/Mapscript extension provides full map customization capabilities
within the Java programming language.


%package ruby
Summary:       Ruby/Mapscript map making extensions to Ruby
BuildRequires: ruby-devel
Requires:      %{name} = %{version}-%{release}

%description ruby
The Ruby/Mapscript extension provides full map customization capabilities within
the ruby programming language.


%prep
%setup -q -n %{project_owner}-%{commit}

# replace fonts for tests with symlinks
rm -rf tests/vera/Vera.ttf
rm -rf tests/vera/VeraBd.ttf
pushd tests/vera/
ln -sf /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf Vera.ttf
ln -sf /usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans-Bold.ttf VeraBd.ttf
popd

# Force swig to regenerate the wrapper
rm -rf mapscript/perl/mapscript_wrap.c


%build

mkdir build
cd build

export CFLAGS="${CFLAGS} -ldl -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing"
export CXXFLAGS="%{optflags} -fno-strict-aliasing"

cmake -DINSTALL_LIB_DIR=%{_libdir} \
      -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=%{_prefix} \
      -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON \
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE="%{optflags} -fno-strict-aliasing" \
      -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE="%{optflags} -fno-strict-aliasing" \
      -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE=ON \
      -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE="Release" \
      -DCMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH=ON \
      -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON \
      -DWITH_CAIRO=TRUE \
      -DWITH_CLIENT_WFS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_CLIENT_WMS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_CURL=TRUE \
      -DWITH_FCGI=TRUE \
      -DWITH_FRIBIDI=TRUE \
      -DWITH_GD=TRUE \
      -DWITH_GDAL=TRUE \
      -DWITH_GEOS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_GIF=TRUE \
      -DWITH_ICONV=TRUE \
      -DWITH_JAVA=TRUE \
      -DWITH_KML=TRUE \
      -DWITH_LIBXML2=TRUE \
      -DWITH_OGR=TRUE \
      -DWITH_MYSQL=TRUE \
      -DWITH_PERL=TRUE \
      -DCUSTOM_PERL_SITE_ARCH_DIR="%{perl_vendorarch}" \
%if 0%{php_mapscript}
      -DWITH_PHP=TRUE \
%endif # end php_mapscript
      -DWITH_POSTGIS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_PROJ=TRUE \
      -DWITH_PYTHON=TRUE \
      -DWITH_RUBY=TRUE \
      -DWITH_V8=FALSE \
      -DWITH_SOS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_THREAD_SAFETY=TRUE \
      -DWITH_WCS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_WMS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_WFS=TRUE \
      -DWITH_XMLMAPFILE=TRUE \
      -DWITH_POINT_Z_M=TRUE \
      -DWITH_APACHE_MODULE=FALSE \
      -DWITH_SVGCAIRO=FALSE \
      -DWITH_MYSQL=FALSE \
      -DWITH_CSHARP=FALSE \
      -DWITH_ORACLESPATIAL=FALSE \
      -DWITH_ORACLE_PLUGIN=FALSE \
      -DWITH_MSSQL2008=FALSE \
      -DWITH_SDE=FALSE \
      -DWITH_SDE_PLUGIN=FALSE \
      -DWITH_EXEMPI=FALSE \
      ..


make  %{?_smp_mflags}


%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_libexecdir}
%if 0%{php_mapscript}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{php_inidir}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{php_extdir}
%endif # end php_mapscript
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_bindir}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/%{name}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/%{name}/

install -p -m 644 xmlmapfile/mapfile.xsd %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/%{name}
install -p -m 644 xmlmapfile/mapfile.xsl %{buildroot}%{_datadir}/%{name}

# install java
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_javadir}
install -p -m 644 build/mapscript/java/mapscript.jar %{buildroot}%{_javadir}/

# install header
install -p -m 644 *.h %{buildroot}%{_includedir}/%{name}/

cd build
make DESTDIR=%{buildroot} install %{?_smp_mflags}

%if 0%{php_mapscript}
# install php config file
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{php_inidir}
cat > %{buildroot}%{php_inidir}/%{ini_name} <<EOF
; Enable %{name} extension module
extension=php_mapscript.so
EOF
%endif # end php_mapscript


%post libs -p /sbin/ldconfig
%post devel -p  /sbin/ldconfig

%postun libs -p /sbin/ldconfig
%postun devel -p /sbin/ldconfig


%files
%doc README
%{_bindir}/legend
%{_bindir}/mapserv
%{_bindir}/msencrypt
%{_bindir}/scalebar
%{_bindir}/shp2img
%{_bindir}/shptree
%{_bindir}/shptreetst
%{_bindir}/shptreevis
%{_bindir}/sortshp
%{_bindir}/tile4ms
%{_datadir}/%{name}/

%files libs
%doc README
%{_libdir}/libmapserver.so.%{version}
%{_libdir}/libmapserver.so.2

%files devel
%doc README
%{_libdir}/libmapserver.so
%{_includedir}/%{name}/

%if 0%{php_mapscript}
%files -n php-%{name}
%doc mapscript/php/README
%doc mapscript/php/examples
%config(noreplace) %{php_inidir}/%{ini_name}
%{php_extdir}/php_mapscript.so*
%endif # end php_mapscript

%files perl
%doc README
%doc mapscript/perl/examples
%dir %{perl_vendorarch}/auto/mapscript
%{perl_vendorarch}/auto/mapscript/*
%{perl_vendorarch}/mapscript.pm

%files python
%doc mapscript/python/README
%doc mapscript/python/examples
%doc mapscript/python/tests
%{python2_sitearch}/*mapscript*

%files java
%doc mapscript/java/README
%doc mapscript/java/examples
%doc mapscript/java/tests
%{_javadir}/*.jar
%{_libdir}/libjavamapscript.so

%files ruby
%doc mapscript/ruby/README
%doc mapscript/ruby/examples
%{ruby_sitearchdir}/mapscript.so


%changelog
* Sun Jun 04 2017 Jitka Plesnikova <jplesnik@redhat.com> - 7.0.5-3.git208bb3a
- Perl 5.26 rebuild

* Mon May 15 2017 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 7.0.5-2.git208bb3a
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_26_27_Mass_Rebuild

* Mon May 15 2017 Julien Enselme <jujens@jujens.eu> - 7.0.5-1.git208bb3a
- Update to 7.0.5

* Fri Feb 10 2017 Fedora Release Engineering <releng@fedoraproject.org> - 7.0.4-3.gitb4bc015
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_26_Mass_Rebuild

* Tue Jan 24 2017 Devrim Gündüz <devrim@gunduz.org> - 7.0.4-2.gitb4bc015
- Rebuilt for Proj 4.9.3

* Thu Jan 19 2017 Julien Enselme <jujens@jujens.eu> - 7.0.4-1.gitb4bc015
- Update to 7.0.4

* Fri Jan 13 2017 Vít Ondruch <vondruch@redhat.com> - 7.0.3-2.git0f9ece8
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Ruby_2.4

* Mon Dec 12 2016 Julien Enselme <jujens@jujens.eu> - 7.0.3-1.git0f9ece8
- Update to 7.0.3

* Wed Sep 21 2016 Julien Enselme <jujens@jujens.eu> - 7.0.2-1.git4ea78eb
- Update to 7.0.2

* Tue Jul 19 2016 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 7.0.1-4.git6ae2bc6
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Automatic_Provides_for_Python_RPM_Packages

* Tue Jun 28 2016 Julien Enselme <jujens@jujens.eu> - 7.0.1-3.git6ae2bc6
- Disable PHP support.

* Sat May 14 2016 Jitka Plesnikova <jplesnik@redhat.com> - 7.0.1-2.git6ae2bc6
- Perl 5.24 rebuild

* Thu  Feb 25 2016 Julien Enselme <jujens@jujens.eu> - 7.0.1-1.git6ae2bc6
- Update to 7.0.1

* Thu Feb 04 2016 Fedora Release Engineering <releng@fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.2-8
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_24_Mass_Rebuild

* Sun Aug 30 2015 Peter Robinson <pbrobinson@fedoraproject.org> 6.2.2-7
- Rebuild again for GDAL 2.0

* Sun Aug 2 2015 Devrim Gündüz <devrim@gunduz.org> - 6.2.2-6
- Rebuilt for new gdal

* Wed Jun 17 2015 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.2-5
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_23_Mass_Rebuild

* Wed Jun 03 2015 Jitka Plesnikova <jplesnik@redhat.com> - 6.2.2-4
- Perl 5.22 rebuild

* Sat May 02 2015 Kalev Lember <kalevlember@gmail.com> - 6.2.2-3
- Rebuilt for GCC 5 C++11 ABI change

* Wed Mar 11 2015 Devrim GÜNDÜZ <devrim@gunduz.org> - 6.2.2-2
- Rebuilt for Proj 4.9.1
- Add patch for GCC5 build, also add -fPIC to CFLAGS
- Add a patch for swig 3.0.5

* Tue Dec 23 2014 Pavel Lisý <pali@fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.2-1
- Update to latest 6.2 release
- BZ 1048689 - CVE-2013-7262 mapserver: SQL injections with postgis TIME filters
- BZ 747409 - MapServer uses internal AGG and does not depend on agg-devel

* Tue Aug 26 2014 Jitka Plesnikova <jplesnik@redhat.com> - 6.2.1-10
- Perl 5.20 rebuild
- Regenerated the wrapper to work with new Perl

* Sun Aug 17 2014 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.1-9
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_21_22_Mass_Rebuild

* Sat Aug 09 2014 Mat Booth <mat.booth@redhat.com> - 6.2.1-8
- Drop dep on gcj.

* Fri Jun 20 2014 Remi Collet <rcollet@redhat.com> - 6.2.1-7
- rebuild for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Php56
- add numerical prefix to extension configuration file
- add minimal PHP extension load test
- add upstream patch for PHP 5.6 (fix #1111478)

* Sat Jun 07 2014 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.1-6
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_21_Mass_Rebuild

* Tue Aug 27 2013 Orion Poplawski <orion@cora.nwra.com> - 6.2.1-5
- Rebuild for gdal 1.10.0

* Sat Aug 03 2013 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.1-4
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_20_Mass_Rebuild

* Wed Jul 17 2013 Petr Pisar <ppisar@redhat.com> - 6.2.1-3
- Perl 5.18 rebuild

* Tue Jun 11 2013 Remi Collet <rcollet@redhat.com> - 6.2.1-2
- rebuild for new GD 2.1.0

* Tue May 21 2013 Pavel Lisý <pali@fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.1-1
- Update to latest stable release
- BZ 910689 - dependency on bitstream-vera-sans-fonts changed to dejavu-sans-fonts
- BZ 960856 - Missing dependency: bitstream-vera-sans-fonts
- BZ 747421 - Move CGI executable from /usr/sbin to /usr/libexec
- BZ 796344 - Not compatible with JDK7
- BZ 846543 - mapserver-java is incorrectly packaged (missing required native library)
- trim of changelog

* Tue Apr 09 2013 Pavel Lisý <pali@fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.0-2
- changed MS_REL from 6x to 62

* Thu Apr 04 2013 Pavel Lisý <pali@fedoraproject.org> - 6.2.0-1
- Update to latest stable release
- dependency on bitstream-vera-sans-fonts replaced to dejavu-sans-fonts

* Mon Mar 25 2013 Oliver Falk <oliver@linux-kernel.at> - 6.0.3-10.1
- Rebuild - fix changelog (bogus date)

* Sat Mar 23 2013 Remi Collet <rcollet@redhat.com> - 6.0.3-10
- rebuild for http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/Php55

* Thu Feb 14 2013 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.0.3-9
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_19_Mass_Rebuild

* Fri Jan 18 2013 Adam Tkac <atkac redhat com> - 6.0.3-8
- rebuild due to "jpeg8-ABI" feature drop

* Fri Oct 26 2012 Remi Collet <remi@fedoraproject.org> - 6.0.3-7
- conform to PHP Guidelines (#828161)
- add minimal load test for php extension

* Tue Oct 16 2012 Pavel Lisý <pali@fedoraproject.org> - 6.0.3-6
- temporary removed mapserver-java (mapscript) due to build problem
  with jdk7

* Fri Oct 12 2012 Pavel Lisý <pali@fedoraproject.org> - 6.0.3-5
- Merged from 6.0.3-4
- fix of build for php4 and swig > 2.0.4

* Tue Aug 14 2012 Devrim GÜNDÜZ <devrim@gunduz.org> - 6.0.3-4
- Rebuilt for new perl.

* Thu Jul 19 2012 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.0.3-3
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_18_Mass_Rebuild

* Tue Jul 10 2012 Petr Pisar <ppisar@redhat.com> - 6.0.3-2
- Perl 5.16 rebuild

* Sat Jun 30 2012 Devrim GÜNDÜZ <devrim@gunduz.org> - 6.0.3-1
- Update to 6.0.3, for various fixes described at:
  https://github.com/mapserver/mapserver/blob/rel-6-0-3-0/HISTORY.TXT
- Update URL, per bz #835426

* Fri Jun 08 2012 Petr Pisar <ppisar@redhat.com> - 6.0.2-2
- Perl 5.16 rebuild

* Mon Apr 16 2012 Devrim GÜNDÜZ <devrim@gunduz.org> - 6.0.2-1
- Update to 6.0.2, for various fixes described at:
  http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/browser/tags/rel-6-0-2/mapserver/HISTORY.TXT

* Fri Jan 13 2012 Fedora Release Engineering <rel-eng@lists.fedoraproject.org> - 6.0.1-5
- Rebuilt for https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_17_Mass_Rebuild

* Tue Dec 06 2011 Adam Jackson <ajax@redhat.com> - 6.0.1-4
- Rebuild for new libpng

* Thu Jul 21 2011 Petr Sabata <contyk@redhat.com> - 6.0.1-3
- Perl mass rebuild

* Wed Jul 20 2011 Petr Sabata <contyk@redhat.com> - 6.0.1-2
- Perl mass rebuild

* Mon Jul 18 2011 Devrim GÜNDÜZ <devrim@gunduz.org> - 6.0.1-1
- Update to 6.0.1, for various fixes described at:
  http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/browser/tags/rel-6-0-1/mapserver/HISTORY.TXT
- Fixes bz #722545
- Apply changes to spec file for new major version.
```

All works fine and I obtain the followings rpms:

- mapserver-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-debuginfo-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-devel-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-java-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-libs-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-perl-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-python-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
- mapserver-ruby-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm

How may I install these rpms (in a Chef recipe / cookbook, but also to have the exact installations steps is important .....) to obtain MapServer installed ? Are there some specific sequences or priorities?

Examples / suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing you listed sounds like it needs anything special so it would just be a normal `rpm_package` resource AFAICT. Or maybe put them in a Yum repository somewhere since you have to host them anyway so might as well do that and use an even more normal `package` resource.

Comment: I've tried but when I execute my cookbook I receive an error ... `error: Failed dependencies: dejavu-sans-fonts is needed by mapserver-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64   httpd is needed by mapserver-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64  libcairo.so.2()(64bit) is needed by mapserver-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64` ... The same when I try to execute manually from prompt using `rpm -i mapserver-7.0.5-3.git208bb3a.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`                                                                          pm